# Cursor position is not focused on begining of the comment box in Microsoft Edge

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, microsoft-edge

In the Microsoft Edge browser, when adding a comment for a question or answer, by default the cursor position is focused at the second line of the placeholder text.

In the Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers, the cursor position is focused on the very first character of the placeholder text.

**When adding a comment for question:**

> [image: question comment]

**When adding a comment for answer:**

> [image: answer comment]

**Configurations:**

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Browser version: Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0
Zoom: 100%

Comment: Side note: IE does not exhibit this bug; the placeholder is never shown unless the user clicks out of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in Edge and there's nothing we can really do about it.  When Edge encounters a multiline placeholder, it places the cursor at the lower left corner of the text.

```html
<textarea
 rows="4" cols="30"
 placeholder="Line 1&#10;Line 2&#10;Line 3"
></textarea>
```